# Juno fresh install, display unknown, resolution only 640x480, GPU is Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650, display properties will not open

Tags: display, drivers, nvidia

-elementary os Loki worked fine until I upgraded my gpu from geforce 310 to gtx 1650. (I dual boot with windows 10 on separate drives.)

-I decided to wipe loki and install juno but the display problem persists. The display problems seem related to nvidia drivers I believe. They are not available in the app center.

-I tried to install nvidia drivers through terminal, but I got a black screen that flickered intermittently. I wiped and reinstalled juno and am stuck with just one of my 2 monitors working at 640x480.

-I get unknown display and display properties will not open in system settings.

Answer (score 2):

I got it fixed! Special thanks to fosslinux.com for his article here:

https://www.fosslinux.com/1462/how-to-install-nvidia-gpu-drivers-in-elementary-os.htm

He wrote it for Loki but it worked great for me with Juno!

This is foslinux.com's instructions:

*STEP 1: Starting from Loki, elementary OS doesn’t support PPA. So let’s first enable it.  Launch ‘Terminal’ and run the following commands one at a time:*

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*STEP 2: This command will enable PPA and you can use apt-get again in elementary OS.*

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common
```

*STEP 3: Let’s install video graphic sources.*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

*STEP 4: Update again.*

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

*STEP 5: Finally you need to know which nvidia drivers should you install. You can check the latest PPA graphic builds here. Current official (Feb 2017) release is nvidia-370 (370.28). GeForce 8 and 9 series GPUs users need to use ‘nvidia-340’ (340.98) and GeForce 6 and 7 series GPUs users should be using ‘nvidia-304’ (304.132) in the command below. Use 3 digit number accordingly.*

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx
```